# Remove active folder with powershell script

Tags: powershell

So I have to create an installation script for the company I work for. And to bypass some of its policies I need to first run a script that copy's all the files that are needed locally. But those files need to be deleted again. 
The `remove-item` does not work because the script that is running is also in this folder. Placing this script in a different location is no option because of the policies.

I have searched 2 days for a solution and have today and tomorrow left to finish this project.
So please this is the only thing I have get done.

edit:

I found another way around the policies I think. Now i should only delete the powershell script itself is this possible or not?

Comment: Do you want to delete the folder from where Powershell script is running? If YES, it is not possible at all. Beacuse as per my knowledge, O/S deletes all files first, then the folder. Also O/S can't delete files that are already open. You must close the file before delete.

Comment: @RituparnoBhattacharya do you recommend an other solution ?

Comment: You can absolutely delete the PS1 file that is currently running from within that file. Easy to prove. Make a file called `test.ps1` that only contains `Remove-Item test.ps1`. Run it. The file will be gone, there will not be any error. So... what's the difficulty here?

Comment: @Tomalak If i try that it get an error that says that it is in use

Comment: No, it won't. Have you tried the test.ps1 thing as described?

Comment: Can you use `Invoke-Command` to run a `scriptblock` from a remote machine?

Comment: yes I did I tried again an now it works strange but thanks for the help

Comment: This could work. `($(Get-Location).Path) + "\$($MyInvocation.MyCommand)" | Remove-Item`